# Can we Install qemu on Poxmox ? if yes how?

Tags: installation, qemu, proxmox

Can we Install qemu on Poxmox ? if yes how ? because it warns you it will delete some packages of the PVE, even if you continue it doesn't allow you to install it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

proxmox itself is a hypervisor built on the top of qemu-kvm so clearly performing such an operation causes conflicts between two hypervisors.

So, to answer you question:

- "Can we?" yes, of course
- "Is it a good idea?" no